# Django: got error when using upload_to feature

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, imagefield

I want to apply `upload_to` in my Django `models.py`

```
from mongoengine import *
from <project_name>.settings import DBNAME
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField

class Author(Document):
    fk_user = IntField() #points to user id in sqlite3.
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    # photo = FileField()
    photo = ImageField(upload_to="avatars")
    photoname = StringField()
    status = StringField()
    summary = StringField()
    name = StringField()
```

I got this confusing error:

```
    photo = ImageField(upload_to="avatars")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\fields.py", line 1642, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\fields.py", line 1397, in __init__
    super(FileField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

I am using Django 1.5.11

### UPDATE

These are all the modules and versions I use

- Django==1.5.11
- django-braces==1.8.1
- django-debug-toolbar==1.3
- django-embed-video==1.0.0
- django-endless-pagination==2.0
- django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0
- django-storages==1.1.8
- djangotoolbox==1.8.0
- ecdsa==0.13
- httplib2==0.9.1
- mongo==0.2.0
- mongoengine==0.10.0
- MySQL-python==1.2.5
- paramiko==1.15.2
- Pillow==3.2.0
- pycrypto==2.6.1
- pymongo==3.0.3
- requests==2.7.0
- South==1.0.2
- wheel==0.24.0

Comment: You appear to be using Mongo as a backend here? Please do include details about that setup.

Comment: I updated the question. Please review

Comment: And what are the imports in that module?

Comment: The traceback shows the `ImageField` is not the default Django field, so you are using something that doesn't support `upload_to`.

Comment: Updated the question. Yup! That's the answer. Hmmm... Can I still use upload_to even though I use Mongo?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with that codebase.